# Do SQL Queries Need to be that Complicated?

Tags: c#, .net, sql, linq

An open-ended question which may not have a "right" answer, but expert input on this would be appreciated.

Do SQL Queries Need to be that Complicated?

From a Web Dev point of view, as C#/.Net progresses, it seems that there are plenty of easy ways (LINQ, Generics) to do a lot of the things that some people tend to do in their SQL queries (sorting, ordering, merging, etc). That being said, since SQL tends to be the processing "bottleneck" for a lot of apps, a lot of the logic for SQL queries is being moved to the business layer.

As this trend continues, I'm seeing less of a need for large SQL queries.

What do you all think? Are you still writing large SQL queries? If so, is it because you need to or because you are more comfortable doing so than working in the business layer?

Answer (score 4):

What's a "large" query?

The "bottleneck" encountered IME is typically because the tables were modeled poorly, compounded by someone constructing SQL queries that has little to no experience with SQL (the most common issue being thinking SQL is procedural when it's actually SET based).  Lack of indexing is the next most common issue.

ORM has evolved to support native queries -- clear recognition that ORM simplifies database interaction, but can't perform as well as proper SQL query development.

Keeping the persistence handling in the business layer is justified by desiring database independence (at the risk of performance).  Otherwise, it's a waste of money and resources to ignore what the database can handle in far larger loads, in a central location (that can be clustered).

Answer (score 3):

It depends entirely on the processing. If you're trying to do lots of crazy stuff in your SQL which does things like pivoting or text processing, or whatever, and it turns out to be faster to avoid doing it in SQL and process it outside the database server instead, then yes, you were probably using SQL wrong, and the code belongs in the business layer or on the client.

In contrast, SQL excels at set operations, and that's what it should primarily be used for. I've seen an awful lot of applications slowed down because business logic or display code was grabbing a million rows of resultset from the database, bringing them back one at a time, and then throwing 990,000 of them away by doing what's effectively a set operation (JOIN, whatever) outside the database, instead of selecting the 10,000 interesting results using a query on the server and then processing the results of that.

So. It depends on what you mean by "large SQL queries". I feel from the way you're asking the question that what you mean is "overly-complex, non-set-based translations of business/presentation logic into SQL queries that should never have been written in the first place."

Answer (score 2):

*in many data-in/data-out cases*, no.

*in some cases*, yes.

If all you need to work with is a simple navigation hierarchy (mainly focusing on parent, sibling, child, etc), then LINQ and it's friends are excellent choices - they reduce the pain (and effort and risk) from the majority of queries. But there are a number of scenarios where it doesn't work so well:

- large-scale set-based operations: I can do a wide-ranging query in TSQL without the need to drag that data over the network in one large query, and then (even worse) update each record individually (since in many cases the ORM tools will choose individual UPDATE/INSERT/DELETE operations etc). Not only is this slow, it increases the chances of data drift. So to counter that you might add a transaction - but a long-lived transaction (while you suck a glut of data over the network) is *bad*
- simply: there are a lot of queries where hand-tuning it achieves things that the ORMs simply can't; I had a scenario recently where a *relatively basic* LINQ query was performing badly. I hand tuned it (using some `ROW_NUMBER()` etc) and the IO stats went down to only 5% of what they were with the generated query.
- there are some queries that are exceptionally difficult to express in some query syntax options, and even if you do - would lead to bad queries. Yet which can be expressed very elegantly in TSQL: example: [Linq to Sql: select query with a custom order by](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4882923/linq-to-sql-select-query-with-a-custom-order-by/4883108#4883108)

Answer (score 1):

This is a subjective question.

IMO, SQL (or whatever query language you use to access the db) should be as complicated as necessary to solve performance problems.

There are two competing interests:

**Performance:** This means, load the least amount of data you need in the smallest number of queries.

**Maintainability:** Load as much as possible (lets say, as it makes sense) with the simplest, most reusable kind of query and do everything else in memory.

So you always need to find your way between performance and maintainability. This is actually nothing special - that's what you do when programming all the time.

Newer ways of doing db queries don't change a lot in this situation. Even if you use NHibernate's HQL, you consider performance and maintainability. You already went a step to maintainability, but you may fall back to SQL to tune some queries.

Comment: I don't think it's subjective so much as inflammatory

Comment: @OMG: Inflammatory ...? The definition of "complicated" already is subjective.

Comment: There may be people who like writing sql more then everything else ... for me it's like falling back to assembler for performance tuning. To me there is nothing inflammatory on questioning SQL.

Comment: Except complicated SQL can be 1000 tiems faster than wpulling the data and writing code to manipulate it. Not sure what you do, but I work currently on a 6000gb sql database project. The idea of doing our aggregations outside sql sends shudders down to everyone.

Comment: That's what I mean by my answer. Where is the "except" part?? I mean, "sending shudders" is not really an argument. Some things feels bad and that's exactly what they are. On the other hand, some people don't really involve in new technologies just because of their feelings. There may not be many options for your 6TB database, who knows, but when you switch to problems with just a few millions or even thousands of records, you should change your mind. That's all I mean: find your way between performance and maintainability.

Answer (score 0):

For me, the deciding factor between writing a giant sql query or a bunch of simple queries and then do everything in the code is usually performance. The latter is preferred but if it goes way too slow, I'll do the former (Sql is optimized for data processing after all).

The reason because I prefer the latter is, that in general my team is more comfortable with code then sql queries. I like sql a lot but if a giant sql query means that I'm only one who can debug/understand it in a reasonable amount of time, that's not a good thing. Another reason is also that with a giant query, you will usually program some business logic in it. If I have a business layer, I prefer too have as much of my business logic there as possible.

Off course, you could decide to stuff all your business logic in stored procedures. Your program is then nothing more then a GUI interface to the API of your database. It depends on the requirements of your project and if your team can handle this.

That said, you give Linq as an alternative technology. I have noticed in my team that thanks to my experience with SQL, I'm very comfortable with Linq while my colleagues are not. The problem on a deeper level is procedural vs set based thinking. Linq is comparable to sql. If you are not comfortable with SQL, chances are you won't be with Linq.